# oracle dynamic query issue: how to get value into a variable which is coming as a part of string

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I need help in dynamic query for the following scenario.

I have a procedure A in which I am storing a string in an output variable which will be passed to a procedure B.

Procedure B receives tablename also as an input parameter but procedure A doesn't, however procedure A also uses the tablename variable.

I am thinking of how to use tablename variable in procedure A string such that when the string is passed to procedure B, its input variable value of tablename gets assigned to the tablename variable in the string of procedure A.

I will try to explain with some code sample. It's a sample and no actual code.

```
proc A
begin
--- string that uses tablename but has no variable input for tablename.

mystr:='AND DAY_OF_WEEK_ID IN (SELECT B.DAY_ID FROM DAY_OF_WEEK B 
                                             INNER JOIN CD.' || 'v_tableName' || ' CD
                                             ON TRIM(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(CD.GMT_SEIZ_DT_TIME,''YYYYMMDDHH24MISS''), ''DAY'')) = B.NAME WHERE B.DAY_ID IN (1,7))';

end;

proc B
(v_tablename, mystr)
begin
mystr2:= 'insert into sometable
select ' || mystr || ' from ' || v_tablename
end;
```

so the mystr string already contains tablename variable for which I want the same value to be assigned as the variable v_table_name of procedure B.

I apologies if I have made the scenario too complex but I couldn't find a better way.

Regards.

Comment: I cant understand the question

Comment: Sorry about that. I knew my explanation is complex. Posting actual code was not feasible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In procedure B you need to substitute the placeholder in the passed string with the actual table name.

Your posted pseudo-code is a bit garbled, but it seems the placeholder in the string generated by procedure A is `'v_tablename'` and the actual table name in procedure B is held in a variable called `v_tablename`. That being the case, this would work for you:

```
mystr := replace(mystr, 'v_tablename', v_tablename);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I apologize for poor explanation of the problem but you still got the point.

Comment: I've been doing this a long time :) But a better naming policy would have created a clearer question.